# Using Model addAttribute for error handling in the UI

Tags: spring

Example Sample Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addEmployee(Model model, EmpTO empTO, BindingResult bindingResult){
    try {
        empService.saveOrUpdateEmployee(empTO);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof InvException) {
            model.addAttribute("error", ((InvException) e).getError());
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("error", PresentationUtil.handleApplicationRuntimeError(e));
        }
        return new ModelAndView("emp/save");
    }
    empTO = new EmpTO();
    return new ModelAndView("emp/home");
}
```

## Questions:

1. Is the above is the correct approach?
2. Can we store the error code and description in a DB table or hard-coded string and let UI handles the error codes?
3. Is this is a standard industry practice?

Thank.s

Answer (score 0):

We use `@ExceptionHandler` annotation which allows us to handle exceptions outside the Controller methods. No need to put the error codes in the database table.

Exception class :

```
public class InvException extends RuntimeException {
    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMsg;
    //setter/getter
    ...
}
```

And In Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addEmployee(Model model, EmpTO empTO, BindingResult bindingResult){
   ...
   } catch (InvException e) {
      throw new InvException("E400", "This is Inv Exception");
   } catch (Exception e) {
       throw new Exception(...);
   }
}

@ExceptionHandler(InvException.class)
public ModelAndView handleMyOwnException(InvException ex) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("your specific error view");
    model.addObject("errCode", ex.getErrorCode());
    model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getErrorMsg());
    return model;
}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception ex) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("your generic error view ");
    model.addObject("errMsg", "There is a exception");
    return model;
}
```

This `@ExceptionHandler` applies to single controller. It can be applied to all the controllers by creating a new class and annotating it with `@ControllerAdvice`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionController {
    @ExceptionHandler(InvException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleMyOwnException(InvException ex) {...}
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception ex) {...}
}
```

Comment: Can we use @ControllerAdvice or handle as above. which one would be the best approach ?

Comment: We definitely prefer `@ControllerAdvice`.A controller advice allows you to use exactly the same exception handling techniques but apply them across the whole application, not just to an individual controller. Ref [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Can u pls help me with an open source project link to download which uses controlleradvice as a pratice for the design